# Are there any rules/conventions for transmitting coordinates in CW?

Tags: cw, procedure

I am wondering how hams transmit coordinates in Morse code. Considering that coordinates can be represented in many different formats (such as DD, DDM, DMS, WGS84, etc.) and that an error in the decoding of the coordinates can mean a lot, it seems reasonable to think that there are some rules in this regard.

Are there any rules/conventions for transmitting coordinates in Morse code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Send your Grid Square**](http://www.arrl.org/grid-squares). It's short, includes your latitude and longitude, and is in common use.

For example, mine is EM37. For greater location accuracy, I would send EM37CG.

> A grid square measures 1° latitude by 2° longitude and measures
>   approximately 70 × 100 miles in the continental US. A grid square is
>   indicated by two letters (the field) and two numbers (the square).
>
> Each subsquare is designated by the addition of two letters after the
>   grid square, as FN44ig. These more precise locators measure 2.5
>   minutes latitude by 5 minutes longitude, roughly corresponding to 3 ×
>   4 miles in the continental US.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, 'The only abbreviation recommended to indicate a Maidenhead reference in Morse code and radio teleprinter transmission was "LOC", as in "LOC KN28LH" '

Answer (score -3):

In Morse Code you would give your longitude and latitude. If you have a ham license the number denotes your location while the prefix of the ham’s call sign (call sign = license) denotes the country code. This means that when you start or find a cw conversation in which you wish to participate, the first thing you do is send your call sign.

Comment: I recognize that the poster is struggling with the English language but the general content demonstrates a complete lack of knowledge about the subject.